# Foreign Key Laravel 8 foreignId + constrained - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I have 'categories_blogs' and 'blogs' migration.

I'm using new foreignId, constrained with bigint, I get this follow error when add a row in 'blogs' table:

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`blogs`, CONSTRAINT `blogs_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories_blog` (`id`))

```
    Schema::dropIfExists('categories_blogs');

    Schema::create('categories_blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('category_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

   Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained('categories_blog');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
  });
```

Instead without bigint and old foreign key way, works fine:

```
Schema::dropIfExists('categories_blogs');

Schema::create('categories_blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('category_name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('blogs')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('slug');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->longtext('content');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

How can I fix it? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints), `constrained()` method will use conventions to determine the table name :

```
$table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained('categories_blogs');
```

Comment: You are right! that was the problem, an incredible oversight. thanks!

Comment: Dont forget to mark the answer as accepted ✅

Comment: Yes, I done, but you deleted it. Issue it was only bacause I used constrained('categories_blog') instead constrained('categories_blogs').